# Java: Как синхронизировать потоки?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить метод `writeIntoExcel` только после завершения работы всех потоков, запущенных в цикле `for`, в таком коде:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String vacans;
    for (String v : parsing.parsing_list(read_console.read_line())){
            new parsing(v).start();
    }

    exel.writeIntoExcel(parsing.AllVacans);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `join`.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String vacans;
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String v : parsing.parsing_list(read_console.read_line())){
            Thread t = new parsing(v);
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
            if (t.isAlive()) {
                    t.join();
            }
    }

    exel.writeIntoExcel(parsing.AllVacans);
}
```